# Invalid Binary - iphone app submission

Tags: iphone, ios, binary, app-store

Receiving this error after submission to Apple saying my binary is invalid.

Invalid File Name - Your package contains a file '   .app/FBUserSettingsViewResources.bundle' with **a name that contains invalid characters. Avoid using control characters in the file names.
Invalid File Name - Your package contains a file '**     .app/es.lproj/RematchButton@2x.png' with a **name that contains invalid characters. Avoid using control characters in the file names.
Invalid File Name - Your package contains a file '**     .app/VU.png' **with a name that contains invalid characters. Avoid using control characters in the file names.**

it appears that the error is with the space before the ".app' in each path.

Any ideas how to fix?

Thanks!

Comment: check properly there  name of images that have contation space like icon .png or other images name that you give so please check and then create binary do not space Between extension and File name

Comment: There is no space in the filename.  The error is exactly as it is above.  I need to know what the " .app" is referring to. Thanks

Comment: Do you happen to have a trailing space in your app name?

Comment: Nope.  Not sure what happened here.  My target name is blank, and I cannot change it.  So everywhere the target name is referenced, it is blank.. causing the paths to be off.

Answer (score 1):

Check the path for these images.

It sounds like you might have added the images from another application's .app directory.  When you add an image to your project check the box that says "Copy".

To check the location of the images:
Select the Image on the left in Xcode and select the "File Inspector" on the right.  You want the images to be located within the same directory as your project.

Comment: That's not it.  It looks like my target name is gone.. and it will not let me edit it.  Any ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember the exact scenario, but I've had something similar happen to me in the past. I think I resolved it by removing the troublesome files from Build Phases>Copy Bundle Resources then re-adding them to the project. Not ideal, but it seemed to work!